# Autogenerate an email in an outlook and attach the currently open word document with VBS

Tags: vbscript, outlook, ms-word

I want to write a VBS macro to auto generate an email in outlook and attach a word document. I currently have a macro that does this for excel, but I can't get it to work for Word. I can't figure out for the life of me what my "FName= " should be. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have:

```
Sub AutoEmail()
    On Error GoTo Cancel

    Dim Resp As Integer
    Resp = MsgBox(prompt:=vbCr & "Yes = Review Email" & vbCr & "No = Immediately Send" & vbCr & "Cancel = Cancel" & vbCr, _
    Title:="Review email before sending?", _
    Buttons:=3 + 32)

    Select Case Resp

        'Yes was clicked, user wants to review email first
        Case Is = 6
            Dim myOutlook As Object
            Dim myMailItem As Object

            Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set otlNewMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            FName = ActiveWord & "\" & ActiveWord.Name

            With otlNewMail
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .Subject = ""
            .Body = "Good Morning," & vbCr & vbCr & "" & Format(Date, "MM/DD") & "."
            .Attachments.Add FName
            .Display

            End With


            Set otlNewMail = Nothing
            Set otlApp = Nothing
            Set otlAttach = Nothing
            Set otlMess = Nothing
            Set otlNSpace = Nothing


        'If no is clicked
        Case Is = 7
            Dim myOutlok As Object
            Dim myMailItm As Object

            Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set otlNewMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            FName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

            With otlNewMail
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .Subject = ""
            .Body = "Good Morning," & vbCr & vbCr & " " & Format(Date, "MM/DD") & "."
            .Attachments.Add FName
            .Send
            '.Display
            'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            'Application.SendKeys "%s"

            End With

            'otlApp.Quit

            Set otlNewMail = Nothing
            Set otlApp = Nothing
            Set otlAttach = Nothing
            Set otlMess = Nothing
            Set otlNSpace = Nothing


        'If Cancel is clicked
        Case Is = 2
        Cancel:
            MsgBox prompt:="No Email has been sent.", _
            Title:="EMAIL CANCELLED", _
            Buttons:=64

    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

May it is a bit late, but I want to solve it for future use.
You want to have the active document as your file name (FName).

```
FName = Application.ActiveDocument.Path + "\" + Application.ActiveDocument.Name
' .Path returns only the Path where the file is saved without the file name like "C:\Test"
' .Name returns only the Name of the file, including the current type like "example.doc"
' Backslash is needed because of the missing backslash from .Path

otlNewMail.Attachements.Add FName
```

May you also want to save your current document before sending it via outlook, otherwise you will send the document without the changes made.

```
Function SaveDoc()
    ActiveDocument.Save
End Function
```

I hope that this will help others, because the code from the question helped me a lot while scripting a similar script.